# Is there any species of raptor that lived in areas with snow?

Tags: internal-consistency, dinosaurs

I'm writing a fictional story in wich scientists invent a time machine and they send a crew of people back to the past to test their invention. The crew goes inside, activates the time machine and end up somewhere at the mesozoic era. When they step out they find themshelves in cold snowy forest. The crew ventures out, but at some point they're attacked by a group of raptors. Now I wan't to ask, could raptors live in places like this (cold with snow)? If yes, wich raptor species could be? (I'm asking so that I know what would be the most accurate size of the raptors in my story).

Comment: Do you have any evidence that there were snowy forests during Mesozoic?

Comment: You might want to clarify the question. "Raptor" normally refers to birds of prey, like hawks, owls and eagles. From your question, I suspect that is not what you're asking for.

Comment: Yes, there were arctic biomes... escpecially during the Cretaceous

Comment: @JulPal, that's not what the links you gave state

Comment: I've editted to change Raptor to Theropod, since I think what you actually want is any carnivorous bipedal dinosaur, not a modern bird.

Comment: @JamesK, the edit which drastically change the content of the question (like yours) are better left to the OP. It's their question, after all.

Comment: By the way, are you sure this is really worldbuilding? Since it's asking about real dinosaurs and where they lived, it might be a question for Earth Science.SE

Comment: You may want to watch episode 5 of the documentary series *Walking with Dinosaurs* named *Spirits of the Ice Forest*. It doesn't show any raptor but it gives a nice insight on life in the polar forests in the mid Cretaceous and it does feature a polar Allosaurus.

Comment: Also check out the wiki article [South Polar region of the Cretaceous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Polar_region_of_the_Cretaceous#Dinosaurs) mentioning some dinosaurs of different clades, including megaraptorians like [Australovenator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australovenator) and [Rapator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapator) or generally read about East Gondwana, which includes Antarctica and Australia with the latter partly being part of the polar region (southeast Australia).

Comment: And [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Australian_and_Antarctic_dinosaurs) is a list of dinosaurs having lived in the arctic regions of the Jurassic and Cretacious.

Comment: Given the recent rule change to allow a wider range of questions than "traditionally" acceptable on WB SE, I'm somewhat surprised to find this question closed as off-topic.  Seems as on-topic as many of the physics, chemistry, ballistics, economics and political questions we get and allow which are linked to real world scenarios.  Particularly odd given the "reality-check" tag.  As has often been said here by people, just because it's on-topic elsewhere doesn't mean it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

There are dinosaurs known from artic regions during the Mesozoic. During the Cretaceous, several dinosaur species lived in polar forests.

Recent discoveries from northern polar region are: Edmontosaurus (herbivore), Gorgosaurus (carnivore), Troodon (carnivore), Dromaeosaurus (carnivore), Pachycephalosaurus (herbivore), and Thescelosaurus (herbivore)

Discoveries from Australia and South Pole region: Antarctopelta (herbivore) —
Atlascopcosaurus (herbivore), Australovenator (carnivore), Austrosaurus (herbivore), Cryolophosaurus (carnivore), Diamantinasaurus (herbivore),
Diluvicursor (herbivore), Fulgurotherium (herbivore),
Glacialisaurus (ombivore), Kakuru (omnivore), Kunbarrasaurus (herbivore),
Leaellynasaura (herbivore), Minmi (herbivore), Morrosaurus (herbivore), Muttaburrasaurus (herbivore), Ozraptor (carnivore), Qantassaurus (herbivore),
Rapator (carnivore), Rhoetosaurus (herbivore), Savannasaurus (herbivore),
Serendipaceratops (herbivore), Timimus (omnivore), Trinisaura (herbivore),
Walgettosuchus (carnivore), Wintonotitan (herbivore)

To answer your question... Yes, you have Rapator, Dromaeosaurus, and Troodon (if you want small "raptor-like" hunters) in arctic climates.

See [Science Magazine](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/295/5557/979)

[Or even a full documentary called Arctic Dinosaurs](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/nature/arctic-dinosaurs.html)

[Or a nicely illustrated book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0975837028)

[See here for a full list of polar dinosaurs from Australia and Antarctica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Australian_and_Antarctic_dinosaurs)

[One more good article about polar dinosaurs including dromaeosaurids and "Raptors"](http://www.eartharchives.org/articles/dinosaurs-of-the-north-pole/)

Comment: I think you are not answering the question: quoting from one of your links "Although Antarctica in the Cretaceous was in the southern polar region, the Earth had a much warmer climate during this time period, and the continent would have been ice-free." So, they lived in current Antarctica, but not in snow forests.

Comment: Ice-free, as in not covered by a continental ice shelf. There may well have been winters with snow at various points of time.

Comment: Ice-free doesn't mean free of permafrost and snowy forests. To quote the Science article: In southeastern Australia, evidence for the contemporaneous presence of permafrost, ice wedges, and hummocky ground in association with dinosaur-bearing deposits during the late Early Cretaceous (105 to 115 million years ago) has been found. This suggests that these animals [HN10] lived there when mean annual temperatures ranged between -6°C and +3°C (7).

Comment: There is evidence for ice existing on land during the Cretaceous period.http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1988Natur.333..547F

Comment: Rapator is actually a Megaraptor and is suspected to be of 9m length (in comparison: Australovenator, which is another Megaraptor of the southern polar region is thought to be 6m length and 2m in height).